# raspberry: icecc and mixing native gcc compiler with gcc cross compiler

Tags: gcc, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I am setting up raspberry pi 4B cluster using slurm and icecc.
And i want to add x86_64 linux nodes as well (heterogeneous cluster - but running ubuntu 64 bit on all nodes).
'icecc' is working now for the raspberries. 
Next step is to add the x86_64 linux nodes for distributed compilation using cross compiler.
The cross-compiler is already available on x86_64. But the icecc-scheduler (running on x86_64 and distributing among the raspberries only currently) is not using that. Maybe because of different versions or executable names?

**raspberry**

```
ubuntu@raspi-4B-02:/var/cache$ /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++-9 --version
aarch64-linux-gnu-g++-9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

**x86_64**

```
frank@frank-M470-2:~$ /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ --version
aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Do i need to compile 9.3.0 "aarch64-linux-gnu-" cross-compiler for x86_64 and name it /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++**-9** on x86_64? (or better install on **all** machines on /opt/linux/... to not get in conflict with package management).
Or can i - for the time being - restrict to 7.5.0 compiler features and use the mix of compiler versions?

Answer (score 1):

1. if not yet exists: temporary add to /etc/apt/sources.list

   deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy main
2. install

   sudo apt-get install g++-9-aarch64-linux-gnu
3. if you added 1): remove it again
4. check

**x86_64**

```
frank@frank-M470-2:~$ /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++-9 --version
aarch64-linux-gnu-g++-9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-13ubuntu1) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

3. use 'icecc-create-env' to build the build environment for remote compilation:

   icecc-create-env --gcc /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-9 /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++-9
4. copy build environment on raspberry and use it via env var:

   export ICECC_VERSION="x86_64:/mnt/clusterfs/CROSS/aarch64-x86_64.tar.gz"